# (MATLAB, App Designer) How can I write a callback function for Sine Button?

Tags: matlab, callback, calculator, trigonometry, designer

The first screenshot is the frontend of  project.
The second screenshot is a specific portion of the backend of the project.
The screenshots are as links.

The aim of this question is that whenever I press the sin function and assign to it a value (Example: Sin(45)), I want the calculator to calculate that value.

Can someone please guide me regarding this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is: How to assign a callback function for the Sine button ?